# How to run a development realm for Level > 1 aside from live realms on AzerothCore wotlk 3.3.5a

Tags: azerothcore

I would like to have development realm (`worldserver`) which would use my `authserver` (production) so I can test my development code live.

Also I would like to be able to connect to this realm only if I am Account Level > 1.
So GM or Administrators.

I know trinity had this. But not sure how to do this.

Thank you.

I tried running additional `worldserver` which is fine. But how to make it only available to GM and Admins?

Answer (score 1):

Just set `allowedSecurityLevel` to `1` in the`realmlist` table of the `acore_auth` database.

Documentation here: http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/realmlist#allowedsecuritylevel